# BigQuery: Access Denied: User does not have permission to query table... perhaps it does not exist in location US

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run

I'm using the Go client for Bigquery with our setup located (as far as I can tell) entirely in the EU location, but I see some errors stating

```
Access Denied: Table <table>: User does not have permission to query table <table>, or perhaps it does not exist in location US
```

My understanding is that if my dataset and tables are in EU, the jobs will also be run there. However, I can see in the log details that the job is labeled as using the US location:

```
resource: {
  labels: {
    location: "US"
    project_id: "<project_id>"
  }
  type: "bigquery_project"
}
```

The CloudRun instance this is running from is also in the EU, specifically `europe-west6`.

Not sure how to fix this.

Per comment from [guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere), here's a rough approximation of the code:

```golang
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, 'my-project')
if err != nil {
    return false, err
}

checkQuery := fmt.Sprintf(`
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM %s
    WHERE Id = @id`,
    'tableName',
)

q := client.Query(checkQuery)
q.Parameters = []bigquery.QueryParameter{
    {
        Name:  "id",
        Value: id,
    },
})

type check struct {
    Count int64
}
var check flightCheck
it, err := q.Read(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return false, err
}

if err := it.Next(result); err != nil {
    s.log.Error(err, "failed to get query result")
    return false, err
}
return check > 0, nil
```

Comment: Are you certain the user actually has permission to query the table? Often this is the actual cause and the region note can be misleading.

Comment: Yes, the service account has the correct roles. Other operations are running fine.

Comment: Can you share you code?

Comment: did you try setting up the query location to EU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had something going on with how my project name was being generated via code, where my environment was being appended twice, so `project-dev` became `project-dev-dev`, which I missed in the error message. So I was missing that the table name was `project-dev-dev.dataset.table` instead of `project-dev.dataset.table`. ‍♂️

tl;dr Make sure your project name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the location `q.Location = "EU"`. (If it's multi-region in EU you can use `EU` or you need to find out the exact region and use something like `europe-west2`